# Neutron star aliens come to visit Earth. As they leave, they give us three gifts including removing black holes from the Sun

Tags: story-identification, novel

Hard SciFi book, with nearly 2 dimensional life (on a neutron star) that goes zipping past earth. They see our sun and that sparks their interest in space (they evolve super-fast).

We send a spaceship, and eventually they communicate with us, reading our entire list of knowledge in just one or two of their generations. One of their tiny space-ships detects (and removes) cancer from a female human astronaut.

As their world leaves our system they give us 3 gifts - the first of which is removing tiny black holes from the core of our sun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description of fast-moving life on a neutron star makes me immediately think of *[Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg)* by Robert L. Forward.

> Dragon's Egg is a 1980 hard science fiction novel by Robert L. Forward. In the story, Dragon's Egg is a neutron star with a surface gravity 67 billion times that of Earth, and inhabited by cheela, intelligent creatures the size of a sesame seed who live, think and develop a million times faster than humans. Most of the novel, from May to June 2050, chronicles the cheela civilization beginning with its discovery of agriculture to advanced technology and its first face-to-face contact with humans, who are observing the hyper-rapid evolution of the cheela civilization from orbit around Dragon's Egg.

And indeed, according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=kvEZmHX8cfwC&pg=PT315&lpg=PT315&dq=%22dragon%27s%20egg%22%20cancer&source=bl&ots=NFz0QkCuHW&sig=FqXAjxsN1UOY1Odpo0gmLqEMQfE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9rvLw8rLXAhUIbSYKHXbNDEUQ6AEIRTAJ#v=onepage&q=cancer&f=false), they deal with a cancer in one of the researchers.

> "Go ahead," Clear-Thinker quickly replied. "What do you need?"
>   "We will want to modify one of the X-ray illuminators to increase its
>   frequency and power output," she said. "Running it at a high power level
>   will burn it out quickly, so it will no longer be available for general
>   illumination, but if we do a careful scan, the focused beam of X-rays should
>   kill the cancer cells with only minimal damage to the rest of the breast."
>   "We have plenty of illuminators," Clear-Thinker said. "Check with the
>   camera crew to find out which one they can spare, and proceed whenever
>   you are ready."

Also, Valorum provided a quote for the removal of the black holes:

> “You are on your own now,” Sky-Teacher said, hearing the tone. “But we have one last present for you. You will need tens of thousands of years to develop fully, and minor nuisances like ice ages on your planet would slow you down. While we were exploring the interior of your Sun, we found five small black holes. There were the four that you already know about and a much smaller one. Since they were disturbing the fusion reactions in your Sun, we removed them for you. Now the Sun will stay stable while you are learning from the HoloMem crystals.”

Comment: That's the one - the quote above is spot-on! Thanks!